# How to get Address from Latitude & Longitude in Django GeoIP?

Tags: python, django, geolocation

I cannot see anything in their API to do this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoip/#geoip-api

Or should I just use Google API for Reverse Geocoding?

Answer (score 7):

Solution - call this URL and parse it's JSON.

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=%f,%f&sensor=false
```

Answer (score 7):

Use geopy, it can handle multiple geocoders including googlev3.

```
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3
geolocator = GoogleV3()
location = geolocator.reverse("52.509669, 13.376294")
print(location.address)
>>> Potsdamer Platz, Mitte, Berlin, 10117, Deutschland, European Union
```

install with pip:

```
pip install geopy
```

infos found on: https://github.com/geopy/geopy

Comment: I used same code but when used
print(location.address)     got an error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'address'

Comment: I get the same thing when calling reverse, a list of coordinates

Answer (score 2):

You can use maps API. I've included a snippet which I use to calculate marathon start points converted into a PointField using Postgis with Django. This should set you on your way.

```
import requests

def geocode(data):
    url_list = []
    for item in data:
        address = ('%s+%s' % (item.city, item.country)).replace(' ', '+')
        url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%s&sensor=false' % address
        url_list.append([item.pk, url])

    json_results = []
    for url in url_list:
        r = requests.get(url[1])
        json_results.append([url[0], r.json])

    result_list = []
    for result in json_results:
        if result[1]['status'] == 'OK':
            lat = float(result[1]['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'])
            lng = float(result[1]['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'])
            marathon = Marathon.objects.get(pk=result[0])
            marathon.point = GEOSGeometry('POINT(%s %s)' % (lng, lat))
            marathon.save()

    return result_list
```

Comment: Cheers but I was after getting "Address" (as output) from Lat & Long (as input). Your example is the reverse of what I want. I got it working using a similar approach https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=

Comment: instead of address, use your lat long values and inspect the incoming json results. you will find address in there.

Answer (score 2):

@rawsix answer seems smart for a django user.
Note however that the location returned by `geolocator.reverse(query)` is a list and not a `Location` object; so attempting to retrieve attribute `address` from it would result in an error.

Usually, the first item in that list has the closest address information. so u can simply do:

```
 location = location[0]
 address = location.address
```

Additionally, instead of passing a string latitude and longitude to the reverse method, you can use a tuple and it must be the `latitude` before the `longitude`. You can do:

```
 from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3()
 geocoder = GoogleV3()
 location_list = geocoder.reverse((latitude, longitude))
 location = location_list[0]
 address = location.address
```