# Get address from given coordinate using python

Tags: visual-studio-code, python, coordinates, street-address

I have some longitude latitude coordinates and I want to convert it to a specific address using Python. Do you know how to do that? Thank you I am new here.

Comment: Have a look at [geopy](https://pypi.org/project/geopy/)

Comment: Related (maybe dup) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942894/how-to-get-address-from-latitude-longitude-in-django-geoip

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The method that you mean called Reverse Geocode.
You can use Nominatim (OSM) for free geocode service

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="specify_your_app_name_here")
location = geolocator.reverse("52.509669, 13.376294")
print(location.address)
```

Or if you wanna get better results, you can use Google Geocode service that requires API Key

```
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3
geolocator = GoogleV3(api_key='Your_API_Key')
location = geolocator.reverse("52.509669, 13.376294")
print(location.address)
```

Answer (score 2):

use geopy,
this is a script I made myself, you can use it

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from os import system, name
```

those are your imports.
then you would want to define a clear function, this will come in play later

```
def clear():
    if name == 'nt':
        _ = system('cls')
    else:
        _ = system('clear')
```

then define the useragent:

```
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="coordinateconverter")
```

i have it set as coordinateconverter because this is my project name

then define your address:

```
address = '42.2817131, -83.7465425'
```

that was the ann arbor hands on museum address

then actually convert it:

```
location = geolocator.reverse(address)
print(location)
```

this is untested code so it may not work, but it should